# Binding complex object .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model view that has a list of objects in it, so it has a list of other class in it:

```
         public class CpdTestFeedbackFormModel
        {
            public Guid WebsiteKey { get; set; }
            //
            //some other simple fileds
            public List<SelectListItem> StarItems;
            public List<CpdFeedbackQuestionAnswerModel> Questions;
    
            public CpdTestFeedbackFormModel()
            {
                //some initialization
            }
      }
```

and the other class definition:

```
 public class CpdFeedbackQuestionAnswerModel
    {
        public Guid Questionkey { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string QuestionType { get; set; }
        public int RatingAnswer { get; set; }
        public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

I render my data like this in the view:

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitFeedbackAnswers", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new
    {
        enctype = "multipart/form-data"
    }))
    {

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.WebsiteKey)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Testkey)
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Feedback Questions</h1>
                @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
                {
                  
                    <p>Q.<span>@Model.Questions[i].Question</span></p>
                    <p>
                        @if (@Model.Questions[i].QuestionType == "Star Rating")
                        {
                            @foreach (var starItem in Model.StarItems)
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Questions[i].RatingAnswer, starItem.Value)
                                @Html.Label(starItem.Text)
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Questions[i].Questionkey)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Questions[i].Question)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Questions[i].QuestionType)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Questions[i].RatingAnswer)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Questions[i].TextAnswer)

                        }
                    </p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
                <button type="submit" data-type="submit" class="bg-btn-primary">
                    Save Answer
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

when I inspect the view binding seems perfect:

[image]

but in my controller, the **questions** field is empty all other data are coming ok except that list.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<StatusCodeResult> SubmitFeedbackAnswers(CpdTestFeedbackFormModel model)
```

did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having another look I noticed a mistake in my CpdTestFeedbackFormModel class, my Questions don't have a get; set; method!! and that's it, it's working fine now.

```
public List<CpdFeedbackQuestionAnswerModel> Questions { get; set; }
```

Only missed part.